# Are there any authentic hindi/english translations(with original sanskrit text and transliteration) of the four vedas?

Tags: vedas, book-recommendation, translation

I have searched for an authentic english/hindi translation of the vedas for a long time but have not been able to find any.
The Max Müller,Ralph T.H. Griffith and H.H. Wilson translations are totally flawed along with Dayananda Sarasvati's translation.
Please recommend any authentic translations of the vedas in hindi or english(preferably with the original sanskrit text and/or transliteration).

Comment: I have marked your question as duplicate of another question. Reply to this comment if you find the linked question doesn't solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please Visit [https://www.amazon.com/Veda-Vedas-English-Yajur-Atharva-ebook/dp/B097NF937J](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B097NF937J)

this might be the good resource.
you can also search for Yajurveda,Rigveda,Atharvveda,saamveda directly on amazon.

Comment: The book you linked is translated by Griffith, something OP doesn't want